# Qt application crashes in widget destructor

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

I am having a crash in main window QWidget destructor on the line below. For some unknown reason, d->focus_next contains a dangling pointer. Anyone has any tips what could be causing it?

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc I feel like the screenshot was appropriate here. It wasn't there to "lazily copy the code", the code is from QWidget.cpp that is available online. By pasting a screenshot, I wanted to show the stack trace and values of d->focus_prev and d->focus_next. I believe doing so in a non-screenshot manner would create a mess.

Comment: I think that error is caused by another part of your code.

Comment: I think in the most time [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is not only the way to demonstrating the problem. it also helps you find the problem by yourself when you minimize & trying to recreate a small demo to reproduce the error.

Comment: I was not opposing the MCVE, just reacting to the complaint that I pasted a screenshot. However, since I've at least found a workaround and it doesn't seem to me the bug is in my code, I won't be investigating it further for now, at least not until I encounter the bug again.

Answer (score 1):

Related bug report with example: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68393?attachmentOrder=desc

Looks like a Qt bug related with QTabWidget tab order. Found a workaround where setting the QTabWidget focusPolicy to NoFocus removed the crash.